# Python client authentication with decorators

Tags: python, authentication, python-decorators

I want to build a python client on top of a REST API that uses authentication with a api_token. Hence all api calls require the api_token. As it is pretty ugly to add a field

```
'token=...'
```

e.g.

```
a = f1(5, token='token')
b = f2(6, 12, token='token')
c = f3(2, 'a', token='token')
```

where internally f1 and f2 delegate to the REST api

to each function call. What I would like to have is something like:

```
auth = authenticate('token')

a = f1(5)
b = f2(6, 12,)
c = f3(2, 'a')
```

What I can do is to create a class and make all functions member functions. Hence, we would have:

```
auth = calculator('token')
a = auth.f1(5)
b = auth.f2(6, 12,)
c = auth.f3(2, 'a')
```

but that would also be somewhat ugly. I am trying to get this to work with decorators, but to no avail so far.

```
class authenticate:
   def __init__(self, token):
       self.token = token

   def __call__(self, func):
       def functor(*args, **kwargs):
           return func(*args, **kwargs, key=self.authentication)
       return functor 

@authenticate
def f1(a, key):
    data = a
    result = requests.get(1, data, key)
    return result
```

However, this seems to be going nowhere. I am also wondering whether this might work at all as decorators are executed at import time and the token is added at runtime.

Any suggestions on how to make this work or anyone know if there is another standard pattern for this?

Comment: Do you want to use token for calling methods of class? How are you planning to validate it?

Comment: Why do you think making `f1` et al. methods of a single class is ugly?

Comment: I agree with @chepner: a class would probably be the cleanest approach for the case described in the question

Comment: @OlvinRoght I want to call functions that perform a REST API call. I have omitted it, but there is also the stage of mapping the python arguments to json before the call and from json to python types after the call.

Comment: @chepner and Ralf. Ideally, I want to use remote functions as if I use local functions not via a dedicated authentication class. May be it is not possible, I don't know and this is the best that can be done.

Comment: What is a remote function? `f1` et al. have to get the key from *somewhere*, either as an argument or a global variable. A class provides a third option, where the key is attached to an instance that invokes the method.

Comment: the idea would be to give the token to the decorator and the decorator would then add it to the functions such as f1. I am doubting it will work as the decorator runs at import time and want to add the token at runtime. My question is more. Has this been done, and what is the typical solution? If it is the class approach then we use the class approach.

Comment: @Mike are you using a header `Authorisation: Bearer ...` kind of token or?

Comment: @JonClements It would be a JWT token

Comment: err... maybe [edit] your question resembling that? There's also a library extension to `requests` possibly called `requests_jwt` or something...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some hacking around we came up with the following:

```
class authenticate:
   # start empty key
   key = None

   @classmethod
   """ add the token """
   def set_key(cls, token):
       cls.token = token

   def __init__(self, func=None):
       if func is not None:
           self.func = func
       else:
           print('no function')

   def __call__(self, *arg):
       """
       add authentication to function func
       """
       ret = self.func(*arg, auth_key=self.key)
       return ret

@authenticate
def f1(a, key):
    data = a
    result = requests.get(1, data, key)
    return result
```

Then you can run code like:

```
authentication_key = 'token'

print('Initiate class')
authenticate().set_key(key=authentication_key)

print('Run f1(5)')
a1 = f1(5) # no token needed!
a2 = f2(6, 12) # again no token needed as it is in the decorator
print(a1)
```

This works more or less as I hoped and I find it cleaner than the class methods. If anyone has a better suggestion or improvements let me know.